# Could Not Build Application for Simulator-Flutter. Where do I start?

Tags: xcode, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

So I'm getting started with Flutter and am trying to run my application but I can't even run my application because I get this error:

`Could not build the application for the simulator. Error launching application on iPhone 13.`

I get zero syntax errors but the simulator can't even seem to run. I'm not sure even how to diagnose the problem.

Here is my `main.dart` file:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:my_app4/screens/home_screen.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  
  @override 
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Travel UI',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primaryColor: Color(0xFF3EBACE), 
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: Color(0xFFF3F5F7) 
      ),
      home: HomeScreen(),
    );
  }
}
```

And here is my `home_screen.dart` file:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override 
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  @override 
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return Scaffold();
  }
}
```

Does anyone have solutions or ways to diagnose how to solve the problem? Any help would be appreciated because I can't really move forward until I get this resolved.

Comment: Please share the screenshot. The syntax seems fine.